# Direct Carrier Billing

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, payment-processing, subscriptions

Direct Carrier Billing is a payment option provided to subscriber while purchasing an App which will bill the subscriber in their mobile carrier bill (postpaid) or deduct from prepaid balance.

Dear friends I would request to throw some light on how to integrate App in this case with Google Play store or itunes app store API which in turn will call the Mobile Carrier Charging system for charging the subscriber while purchasing paid apps or in App purchases.

Any help would be a boon to me.

Answer (score 4):

Currently Google support Direct Carrier Billing (DCB) for some [countries](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651410?hl=en) which gives Android users the option to pay using their carrier for apps and content in Google Play.

As a mobile application developer, you don't need to integrate anything. 
For purchasing apps, Google Play will offer DCB option as a payment method to end-users if their carrier supported.

For in-app purchases, You need to use Android In-app Billing API and google play will offer the DCB option as a payment method to end-users if their carrier supported.

Check this also ([Decide Whether your App will be Free or Priced](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#decide-price))

To explain more I will list bellow the end user flow:

**REGISTRATION THROUGH GOOGLE PLAY STORE**

1. Go to the Play Store.
2. Click “My Account”.
3. Click “Enable **carrier_name** billing” under Payment methods. (appear only if carrier supported)
4. Google will verify your account while carrier validates your mobile number
5. Enter any country billing address details, “Save” and “Accept” once completed.
6. carrier will appear as your default payment method on Google Play.

**HOW TO BUY IN-APP ITEMS**

1. Open your app.
2. Go to the store for in-game items or in-app purchases.
3. Choose your preferred denomination for the in-app purchase.
4. Click “Buy”.
5. Enter your Google password.
6. Click “Confirm”.
7. Payment will be verified and you will receive an SMS of the successful purchase.